# change password in angular

Tags: angular, angular6, change-password

I'm trying to change password after logging in. I have the **service.ts and component.html**. I want the **component.ts logic**. How to do that?

A beginner here. Go easy on me.

**service.ts**

```
changePassword(data){
  var headers = new HttpHeaders()
    .set('Authorization', 'Token ' + localStorage.getItem('usertoken'));

  var options =  {
      headers: headers
  };
  return this.httpClient
    .patch('/api/auth/change_password/',data, options)
}
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="changePasswordForm" (ngSubmit)="changePassword(changePasswordForm.value)">
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!changePasswordForm.controls['old_password'].valid && changePasswordForm.controls['old_password'].touched}">
    <label for="old_password">Old Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="old_password" class="form-control" id="oldPassword" placeholder="Old Password" [formControl]="changePasswordForm.controls['old_password']" />
    <small *ngIf="changePasswordForm.controls['old_password'].hasError('required') && changePasswordForm.controls['old_password'].touched" class="text-danger">Old Password Required</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" [ngClass]="{'has-error':!changePasswordForm.controls['new_password'].valid && changePasswordForm.controls['new_password'].touched}">
    <label for="new_password">New Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="new_password" class="form-control" id="newPassword" placeholder="New Password" [formControl]="changePasswordForm.controls['new_password']" />
    <small *ngIf="changePasswordForm.controls['new_password'].hasError('required') && changePasswordForm.controls['new_password'].touched" class="text-danger">New Password Required</small>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group text-center">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!changePasswordForm.valid">Change Password</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It totally depends on what your API expects as the request payload.

Comment: {old_password: "abc123", new_password: "abc321"}

Comment: what you wnat exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct, `component.ts` logic is very easy now. Just inject the service in the constructor with the `private` keyboard. Then in the `changePassword()` method call the service sending only the values that you need:

```
changePassword(f) {
  const {old_password, new_password} = f.value;
  this.serviceVar
    .changePassword({old_password, new_password})
    .subscribe(() => console.log('Success!'), 
               () => console.log('A problem occurred..'));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using the Reactive Forms approach, you would already have the `changePasswordForm` defined on your Component Class. You just have to use the `value` property of it.

Inject the service as a dependency in your Component by doing `constructor(private service: Service) {}` and then in the `changePassword()` method, call the `changePassword()` method on your service.

Now since you already have the `FormControl` names as `old_password` and `new_password`, you don't need to explicitly destructure them from the form value.

Try this:

ComponentClass:

```
constructor(private service: Service) {}
...
changePassword() {
  this.service.changePassword(this.changePasswordForm.value)
    .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
}
```